# Rails global variable : is global variable share between http requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have declared global variable in my application controller and i am incrementing it on every http request.

I have tested this functionality and found the global variable is incrementing on every http request.

I am using nginx as a web server and passenger as an application server. i have read many articles on passenger and came to know that passenger creates process for every http request and each proccess will be having their own global variables and therefore global variable is not shareable across every http request. each http request  will have their own copy of global variable. is it true? if it is then why in my case global variable is incrementing on every http request.

****************************nginx conf**********************************

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log info;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/passenger-5.0.7;
    passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/wrappers/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;
        passenger_enabled on;
        client_max_body_size 10000M;
        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
           
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        root /var/www/application/Test/current/public;


        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: This is a near-empty master nginx config. Where's the actual passenger config? I guess, we need one of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`

Comment: please see update config file.

Comment: `worker_processes 1`

Comment: ooohhh.... it means passenger can maximum create only one worker and therefore my global variable is shareable across http request.. right??

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - can you tell me the best way to share data across http requests. i am using rails cache to share counter value across http request..

Comment: Use external storage. Redis, for example.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - i can use that but using it just for keeping track of counter is not the best way...

Comment: Well, depends on what your requirements are. This is my default approach.

Answer (score 2):

> passenger creates process for every http request

This would be extremely inefficient. Passenger doesn't do this. Instead, it creates a pool of workers which keep running and handling requests. Each of workers will have its own value of the global var, which it will update across several requests.

If you use threads for concurrency, then the global var will be shared among all workers, because they will be in the same process.

Comment: That means if there are two or more workers then i may get different global variable value on http requests

Comment: @user2274074: yes, that's what I would expect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2972610/2274074 this answer says passenger shares global variable.

Comment: Ah yes, depends on mode of deployment. If you use threads for concurrency, the global will be shared. If processes - no sharing

Comment: But i am not using any threading still my global variable is shared.

Comment: Show your passenger config

Comment: I don't have experience with Passenger for this, but if you're trying to set variables for your app - what about `ENV` vars at OS level?

Comment: @RichPeck - if i set env vars at os level then can i use those variable in my rails application?? Also are these env vars are shareable across http request? can i perform increment and decrement operation on the env vars??

Comment: You can't change the ENV vars themselves in your app, but they are definitely available on a read-only basis for sure. http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - i also tried multi-threading and still global variables are not shareable. i initialize global variable  with value of 0 then i made two simultaneous http request that increments global counter by one. one request took 2 seconds to completion and counter value was 1 and second request took 20 seconds to completion and counter value was still 1. i was expecting global counter value to be 2.